# Why the app stop after call video player with intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I call video player in my android app with intent for play the video.No error does not occur when playing video.After closing the video player app my application stop .
I use this method :

```
private void play_video() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/nabege" + File.separator + "video"
        + File.separator + videoFileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);}



09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449): Activity com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$6@41b61bf8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$6@41b61bf8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:837)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:608)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1441)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1421)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1415)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:423)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity.onCreate(MovieActivity.java:254)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:169)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do have a `receiver` registered in your `Activity` ?

Comment: @programer138200  Did you read the exception log?

Comment: I debug app But exist no exeption

Comment: Satyen Udeshi : I do not understand your mean .Please advice

Comment: There is missing call to `unregisterReceiver()` in the logcat.

Comment: How do I solve this problem

Comment: There must be a call to `registerReceiver()` somewhere in your activity. so unregister that receiver by calling `unregisterreceiver()` in `onPause`

Comment: Please read  1 Answer .